# Error when deploying a netlify next.js site when trying to implement Clerk

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, netlify

I was trying to add [clerk](https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs) when i got a lot of errors related to typescript issues.

repo is [here](https://github.com/Liquefy7822/FitPlanPro/tree/main)

the site is here: `https://fitplanpro.netlify.app`

the newest error log:

9:37:16 AM: build-image version: 6cae66f783f2b7ff8e3a9cdbb5031761f0b47719 (focal)
9:37:16 AM: buildbot version: 6cae66f783f2b7ff8e3a9cdbb5031761f0b47719
9:37:16 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
9:37:16 AM: Starting to download cache of 430.3MB
9:37:23 AM: Finished downloading cache in 6.779s
9:37:23 AM: Starting to extract cache
9:37:26 AM: Finished extracting cache in 3.199s
9:37:26 AM: Finished fetching cache in 10.051s
9:37:26 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
9:37:26 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
9:37:28 AM: Starting to install dependencies
9:37:28 AM: Python version set to 3.8
9:37:28 AM: Attempting Ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
9:37:29 AM: Using Ruby version 2.7.2
9:37:30 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
9:37:30 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
9:37:30 AM: go version go1.19.12 linux/amd64
9:37:30 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
9:37:31 AM: Started restoring cached Node.js version
9:37:35 AM: Failed during stage 'Install dependencies': dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
9:37:32 AM: Finished restoring cached Node.js version
9:37:32 AM: Downloading and installing node v14.21.3...
9:37:32 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.21.3/node-v14.21.3-linux-x64.tar.xz...
9:37:32 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
9:37:32 AM: Checksums matched!
9:37:34 AM: Now using node v14.21.3 (npm v6.14.18)
9:37:34 AM: Enabling Node.js Corepack
9:37:34 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
9:37:34 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
9:37:34 AM: Started restoring cached corepack dependencies
9:37:34 AM: Finished restoring cached corepack dependencies
9:37:34 AM: No npm workspaces detected
9:37:34 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
9:37:34 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
9:37:34 AM: Installing npm packages using npm version 6.14.18
9:37:35 AM: npm ERR! Unexpected token } in JSON at position 345 while parsing near '...8.0.0
npm ERR!       },
9:37:35 AM: npm ERR!     },
9:37:35 AM: npm ERR!     node_modules...'
9:37:35 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
9:37:35 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-08-24T01_37_35_381Z-debug.log
9:37:35 AM: Error during npm install
9:37:35 AM: Build was terminated: dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
9:37:35 AM: Failing build: Failed to install dependencies
9:37:35 AM: Finished processing build request in 19.711s

i wanted to try and implement clerk's login stuff into my app. but then it knida failed. i made the tsconfig.json in my computer then moved it to github.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.